# How to empty input fields when the page loads WITH JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that emails a users email to me, theres a form that goes to a .php file that sends the email, and upon success it does: window.history.back();. Which works fine, it goes right back to where they were. EXCEPT the information that they typed into the form is still there. How can I have that input be erased when the page loads, or maybe erased right after the user submits the form so that it will be empty when they go back?

I found a few topics about doing this but they all used jQuery, so this question is asking if this can be done WITHOUT jQuery.

Comment: To this date I believed jQuery used javascript.

Comment: I am not sure i am following you. What exactly are u doing to do cause it seems to me that doing window.history.back(); from the PHP script it's not the way to go.

Comment: If you go back and all that, why don't you use ajax instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use plain JavaScript to just empty the values. An example of resetting an `<input>` on an everyday form will go something like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

input.value = '';
```

As seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9NVx/);

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but I can't find a way to get that to work. I attempted putting that into an emptyField function and having that function occur onload, like this onload="emptyField();". But I don't think the window.history.back(); causes the page to "load" necessarily so it is not working.

Comment: The `onload` property is a property of the `window` object. You also just want to reference the method, not call it. So `window.onload = emptyField`. No quotations, no brackets.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! ALTHOUGH, it created another problem at the same time. The "window.onload = emptyField" line is somehow messing up my other javascript functions from executing on load?

Comment: Can I suggest calling the other `onload` methods within an all-encompassing `onload` method? So `window.onload = function(){ onload_method1(); onload_method2(); onload_method3(); }` etc etc.

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly, you are a life saver, thank you! I've learned a lot today.

Comment: There's nothing quite like that 'eureka' moment. Glad I could have helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset the value of the all the input fields. Then, this can be a solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetValues()
{
 var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for(i = 0; i<=x.length-1; i++)//x.length-1 i don't want to reset the value of the last button
  {
  if(x.item(i).type!="button")
  x.item(i).value = "";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="resetValues()">
<input type="text" id="name"><br>
<input type="text" id="address"><br>
<input type="text" id="country"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="resetValues()" value="Reset values">
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you wan to reset some particular input fields. Try this:

```
//In you resetValues() function, replace the code with this
 var x = document.getElementById("name");//your input element id
 var y = document.getElementById("address");//your input element id
 var z = document.getElementById("country");//your input element id
 x.value = "";
 y.value = x. value;
 z.value = y.value;
```

Hope, this works fine for you.

Comment: This is a more in depth answer like the one above, thank you. But like the one above, there seems to be a problem because window.history.back(); doesn't actually activate the onload.